# Map attributes to classes both ways

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes, `Lower` and `Higher1`. When I call the `parse` method of an instance of `Lower` it checks which kind of higher class it represents, in my example I only show `Higher1`. Then it creates an instance of this higher class and returns it. I can convert an instance of an higher class back to an instance of `Lower` by calling it's `build` method.

```
class Lower:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def parse(self):
        if self.data[0] == "a":
            value = self.data[1:]
            return Higher(value)
        else:
            ...


class Higher1:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def build(self):
        return Lower("a" + self.value)
```

So far so good, now I want to create classes for every possible value of the `value` attribute of `Higher1`. Assuming `"green"` and `"blue"` are possible values there were two additionally classes called something like `Higher1Green` and `Higher1Blue`.

`Higher1("blue")` would evaluate to an instance of `Higher1Blue`.

`Higher1("blue").build()` would evaluate to an instance of `Lower` with the attribute `data` beeing `"ablue"`.

My question is if this is possible by only specifying the mapping between for example `blue` and `Higher1Blue` one time and not at multiple locations in the code. I don't care if the classes `Higher1Blue` and `Higher1Green` are generated dynamically or defined using `class`.

---

My first approach was to overwrite the `__new__` method of `Higher1` to be able to return instances of `Higher1Blue` or `Higher1Green` instead. But I couldn't find a way to do the backwards mapping (`Higher1Blue.build()`) without specifying the mapping another time.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but it sorta sounds like you want `Higher`()` to be a factory, not a `class`. `def higher1(value): if "blue" == value: return HigherBlue()` etc ...?

Comment: Have you researched inheritance? You can create subclasses of **Higher1** and override the **__init__** method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse mapping class attributes to classes in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263479/reverse-mapping-class-attributes-to-classes-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following link I was able to achieve what I wanted:

[Reverse mapping class attributes to classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263479/reverse-mapping-class-attributes-to-classes-in-python)

I didn't want to vote for duplicate because it's not exactly the same question and it would have taken a long time to wait for 50 votes, all the time people could spend time on finding a solution when I already got one.